# Rate of heat loss of a block of dry sand over time

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a rectangular block of dry sand I'm using as passive thermal heater, that's heated by the sun.

Dimensions are 1.0m long, 0.5m wide and 0.5m deep ( 0.25 m3 )

Assume the block of sand is stand alone and exposed to +10C air on all sides.

If initial temp of the block of sand is already uniformly at 60C, how long before the temp drops to 20C once its heating source is removed please?

I'm an Elec Eng, not a Mech, and get lost in specific heat, Q etc etc, so I just need a simple way to calculate the time taken for the sand to drop from 60C to 20C please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did an FEA simulation of what you described and tried to characterise the heat loss due to radiation this is my result. The X-axis is hours whilst the y axis is temperature in Kelvin. I omitted natural Grashof convection. The temperature has been taken from a middle point in the block of sand. [image: Temperature evolution with time]
You might be able to use this as a check for any simple way you may identify, but this was simple enough for me.

The Sand properties I used were (found from various sources online):
Heat Conductivity: 0.25 W/(mK)  [Source](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-d_429.html)
Density: 1520 [Source](https://civiltoday.com/civil-engineering-materials/sand/299-bulk-density-of-sand)
Heat Capacity: 830 [Source](https://forum.buildhub.org.uk/topic/30897-calculating-for-the-use-of-sand-for-a-thermal-store/)
Emissivity:0.9 [Source](https://www.thermoworks.com/emissivity-table/)